# Ipad won't load local SWF file from As3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have 2 SWF files that is inside the app, i packeged it with AIR 14.0 to an IPA, it is just an image of a loading screen, but it won't load, when i publish it to test on my ipad.

I am not sure what to do.

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("com/clark/LoadingScreen.swf"));

        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,swfIn);

        e.target.loader.content.width = stage.stageWidth/2;
                e.target.loader.content.scaleY = e.target.loader.content.scaleX;
        e.target.loader.content.x = (stage.width/2)-(e.target.loader.content.width/2);
        e.target.loader.content.y = (stage.height/2)-(e.target.loader.content.height*1.5);

        addChild(loader);
```

Comment: iPad does not support SWF.

Comment: oooo so i can only load SWF in iphones?

Comment: All iOS devices **cannot** load SWF. That's trivial. And Android is dropping SWF support soon.

Comment: But Adobe site says it can tho, if i have AIR for IOS on it."A SWF file containing only assets and no code can be loaded from the application package or over a network." My SWF is just an animated image. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e13.html#WS2f73111e7a180bd0-3db1ea4613c45877121-8000

Comment: This is a different thing. The AIR for iOS App must be generated / exported from Adobe Flash as IPA format. You'd better give up using ActionScript on iOS. It's a fading out technology.

Comment: If you read carefully in your link, it guides you to: http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/. Also, Apple App Store will have high chance of rejecting these Apps, as it is not created by Xcode.

Comment: "ActionScript on iOS. It's a fading out technology." You meant using Actionscript 3 then package it with AIR for IOS to generate IPA is a fading technology? Not sure what you meant.

Comment: Maybe i didnt explain clear enough, i did generate the AIR for IOS app into a IPA file from Flash Pro

Comment: ActionScript / Flash itself is fading out. It's replaced by HTML5. You'd better switch

Comment: Yer you meant for both Desktop and Mobile? because i am doing HTML5 for website stuff, but i am using AS3 for Mobile app stuff.

Comment: Why? You should avoid AS3 for mobile ! HTML5 works great on mobile & desktop platforms.

Comment: I havent had much experience with HTML5 for mobile, i can built webpages and stuff but no experience with Mobile. I am pretty new to APp development and it seemed easiest for me to enter AS3 for mobile. But i am gonna learn HTML5 for mobile. At the moment, i have no idea about anything regarding HTML5 into SDKs or IPAs

Comment: Try Cordova / Selenium / Unity 3D / Qooxdoo . Lots of choices in the market apart from old AS3.

Comment: Sweet, thanks, but people still use Flash to develop Animation right? Because i dont really know other programs that does that.

Comment: Some people working on mobile platform switch to Adobe Edge Animate, while others work out the animation by themselves.

Comment: Many of these comments are either misinformed, plain stupid or irrelevant with the question. 
-Whether with Ios or Android AIR can load external swf.
-Android is not dropping swf support. That's a lie.
-appstore doesn't rejst app not created by xcode. That's a lie.

Answer (score 1):

here is some information from adobe about this topic http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/

Comment: I read thru it and installed the app on the ipad again, it does not prompt any error tho, it just simply does nothing